# My stream crashes after obtaining latitude and longitude twice, and doesn't follow my current position. What is causing this?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

After two geolocation updates, it crashes and doesn't follow me in the map:

```
  StreamSubscription subscription;


    super.initState();
    subscription = getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10).listen(
            (Position position) async {
              getLocation();
              centerScreen(position);
          print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + position.longitude.toString());
        });
  }
```

just to be safe, i tried adding: subscription.resume() to my _onMapCreated (flutter google maps). No impact...

Here's my getLocation:

```
  Future getLocation() async {

    Position position =
        await getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    lat = position.latitude;
    lng = position.longitude;

    setState(() {});
  }
```

and my center screen function:

```
  Future<void> centerScreen(Position position) async {

    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
        zoom: _currentZoom)));
  }
```

This is with the latest release of flutter geolocator and flutter google maps.

I've been trying to figure this out for two days... I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Took it out of my init state. Passed it to getLocation like so:

```
  Future getLocation() async {

    subscription = getPositionStream(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10).listen(
            (Position position) async {
              final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
//    final GoogleMapController currentZoom = await _controller.zoom;
              controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
                  zoom: _currentZoom)));

        });
```

works well.

Answer (score 0):

**GoogleMapFlutter with Geolocator**

```
 // GoogleMapFlutter with Geolocator
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  bool mapToggle = false;
  var currentLocation;

  @override
  //initiate position
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Geolocation
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
      });
    });
  }

  //Location Marker
  Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
    return <Marker>[
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("currentLocation"),
        position: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: "Your Location"),
      )
    ].toSet();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        mapToggle
            //Google Map flutter
            ? GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                markers: _createMarker(),
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(
                        currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                    zoom: 15.0))
            //Loading
            : Center(
                child: Text(
                'Loading.. Please wait..',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)